# [Nokia 3]adb reboot bootloader failed

Tags: adb, bootloader, 7.1-nougat, nokia-3

I have Nokia 3 Android 7.1.1 connected to PC Windows 8.

Problem is:

```
C:\>adb reboot bootloader
reboot failed: -1
```

Reason to do it is to flash/root in future.
Other commands ok:

```
C:\>adb devices -l
List of devices attached
NE1GAM0760502899       device product:TA-1032_00WW model:TA_1032 device:NE1 transport_id:11
C:\>adb reboot
[...really reboot as expected]
C:\>adb reboot recovery
[...really reboot to recovery]
C:\>adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
Version 0.0.1-4500957
Installed as C:\Users\nobody\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
C:\>adb -t 11 reboot bootloader
reboot failed: -1


C:\>adb shell getprop
...
[ro.build.date.utc]: [1511256803]
[ro.build.description]: [TA-1032_00WW-user 7.1.1 NMF26O 00WW_2_15H release-keys]
[ro.build.display.id]: [00WW_2_15H]
[ro.build.flavor]: [NE1_00WW_FIH-user]
[ro.build.host]: [NJ-SW-UBUNTU-S7]
[ro.build.id]: [NMF26O]
[ro.build.product]: [NE1]
[ro.build.tags]: [release-keys]
[ro.build.type]: [user]
[ro.build.user]: [foxconn2]
[ro.build.version.incremental]: [00WW_2_15H]
[ro.build.version.preview_sdk]: [0]
[ro.build.version.release]: [7.1.1]
[ro.build.version.sdk]: [25]
[ro.build.version.security_patch]: [2017-12-01]
...
```

What's wrong?

I can reboot to fastboot manually from recovery menu ok.

Comment: Some devices don't support adb reboot bootloader command such as Samsung devices, may be it's the case for yours too? If you want to boot into the bootloader, first boot in the recovery then reboot to fastboot from the recovery as you already do.

Comment: Have you turned on OEM unlock option in Developer Settings?

Comment: @harpratap , Yes.